# Find the renamed view used by a crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using Crystal Reports 2008 to try to make a copy of an already existing report.  I need to clone the report, and the database view generating the report, and then make a series of changes.

There is only a single view being used by the report, and there's about 400 or so views in the database.  None of the views in the database have the same name as the view in the report, so obviously they renamed the view as they imported it.  And obviously I don't want to go through the views one at a time trying to match up column names.

How do I find the original name of the view being used by the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database | Set Datasource Location..., select the view, expand it, then expand the Properties node.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That allowed me to discover that the report wasn't working in the first place, and that's why I was having so many problems.